# Authentication Needed When Downloading Using WebClient

Tags: c#, web

I'm able to go to http://bsb.apca.com.au/public/BSB_DB.NSF/publicBSB.xsp, and click on "Download BSB" and proceed to download the following file:
http://bsb.apca.com.au/public/CS4BSBDir.nsf/0/B895ACB64BE7D0EECA257ED1001108BE/$File/BSBDirectorySept15-234.csv

I'm trying to do this programatically as seen below however I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

var client = new WebClient();
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client.DownloadFile("http://bsb.apca.com.au/public/CS4BSBDir.nsf/0/B895ACB64BE7D0EECA257ED1001108BE/$File/BSBDirectorySept15-234.csv", @"C:\temp\csvTest.csv");
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server which requires authentication to browse the net, such as a work or university network? I copy & pasted your code, and it successfully downloaded the csv.

Comment: Yeah I am on my work's network.
But how come it lets me do it manually through the web browser?

Comment: Your browser is most likely sending a header or cookie with the request in order to authenticate itself to the proxy. I'd suggest opening up your debugger in your browser (or use something like fiddler) and watch the network tab. Grab whatever headers it's sending (as well as cookies) and add them to your web client request. These values may change periodically, but that's as good as you're going to get without going through the whole authentication process with your webclient